# Proving $(\mathbb{R}, \star)$ is a group using ordered field axioms of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

For example, suppose we are trying to prove that $(\mathbb{R}, \star)$ is a group equipped with a binary operation $\star$. In the proof, is it permitted to use the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is an ordered field? Does this extend to other common sets ($\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z_5}$, etc,) and their properties?

Comment: What is $\star$? If it is not defined explicitly, I don't think that we can prove the statement.

Comment: Regardless of the operation $\star$, can the properties of the ordered field $\mathbb{R}$ be used to prove or disprove that $(\mathbb{R}, \star)$ is a group?

Comment: *Permitted*? Yes. *Helpful*? It depends.

Comment: I voted to close this question as I cannot see why you think you might not be allowed to use this fact. It would be helpful if you explained this more. (Mathematics isn't a game where you can only use certain facts and you will be penalised if you use others - in fact, in maths research, using facts from one area to prove something in a different area is often seen as a *good* thing!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the operation $\star$ should be defined explicitly in order to determine whether $(\Bbb{R},\star)$.

For example, take $\star$ to be the usual multiplication.
Then $(\Bbb{R},\star)$ is clearly not a group since the set has $1$ as the identity but the element $0$ has no inverse in this set.

From the information that $\Bbb{R}$ is a field, you can only conclude that $(\Bbb{R},+)$ and $(\Bbb{R}-\{0\},\cdot)$ are groups.

Comment: And taking ${\star}={+}$ *does* yield a group.